# What I am missing when setting up YourKit Java profiler on Ubuntu 12.04 with IDEA Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, yourkit

This error I get when setting up YourKit Java Profiler

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library /home/adelin/Downloads/YourKitJavaProfiler9.0/yjp-9.0.9/bin/linux-x86-32/libyjpagent.so in absolute path, with error: /home/adelin/Downloads/YourKitJavaProfiler9.0/yjp-9.0.9/bin/linux-x86-32/libyjpagent.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
```

My JVM Is 64 bit. Am I missing thing here ?

I have some E2E tests involv Threads, Sockets and SiteBricks Http webclients. Now that my tests runs very slow about 6 seconds per test which is very slow. I wanted to use the profiler   to watch where the test exactly slows down. My testing frame work is TestNG. When I press right click and press "Profile" I get the above message.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please describe exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try linking to the linux-x86-64 version instead:

/home/adelin/Downloads/YourKitJavaProfiler9.0/yjp-9.0.9/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so

If it's not there, try re-downloading from:

http://www.yourkit.com/download/older.html

Comment: I didn't understood you, how to linking ?

Answer (score 0):

Adelin,

.so are "shared objects" and they contain compiled code. Think of them as a .dll in Microsoft World.
If you put them in the path the native part of the JVM will certainly link to them.

Cheers.